# In ANDROID Applications where should i place database tables

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am bit confuse that where to place the database tables in android.
As i have created tables in the sqlite browser 
please help me...

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite browser will not help you to put your tables in android sqlite db.

Please refer to this guide :

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html